# line break despite z-index?

Tags: php, html, css, line, break

hello i have a problem using z-index. i have a form with some input fields. beside them i have some error divs for echoing the php error messages. the problem i have is, that the error divs, that only will come up when a error is set, leads to a line break for the input fields.

```
.wrapper   #mainframe   #left #frame form fieldset ul .fr {
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
.wrapper #mainframe   #left #frame form fieldset ul input.err {
    width: 180px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    outline:none;   
    background-image: url(../images/error.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 172px 50%;
}
.wrapper #mainframe #left #frame form fieldset ul .erl {
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #f23;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    left: +217px;
    top: 25px;
}
```

here is the html code:

```
<li class="fr">
<label for="a">a</label>
<?php if (isset($errors['a'])):?>
<input class="err" type="text" id="a" name="a" value="<?php echo isset ($_POST['a'])? $_POST['a'] : ''; ?>" tabindex="20" autocomplete="off"/>
<?php if ( isset($errors['a']) 
&& empty($errors['a'][0]) == true ):?>

<?php echo "<div class='erl'>"; 
echo $errors['a'][0];
echo "</div>";
endif;?>

<?php endif;?>
```

so i dont understand why this is happening. i thought using z-index would be something like causing two layers (z-index:0 and z-index:1) so that there should be enough place left and right hand side on the second layer z-index:1. if there is someone who could tell me how to solve this i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to show the HTML output.

Comment: i added the html to my question.

Comment: where are the other css classes like "fr" and "err"?

Comment: sorry, i added the whole css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look for things like padding and margin (http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/) that may be adding unintended spacing and overall width.

Also, check to be sure that whatever elements you apply z-index have their position explicitly declared... also the positioning of the parent elements (http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp).

Finally, I would look at issues with the hasLayout property (http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html). This may be what Vinny is talking about, since Z-index does not change the way the document flows so much as the stack order. Try using position:absolute on your error messages to remove them from the overall flow of the document.

Comment: hello, okay changing position to absolute bewares of line breaking. but now i have the problem that every error div is placed at the same position. so i would have to declare seperate classes for each input field with own positionings.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid line-breakage, you will need to remove the error element from the flow of the document. The `z-index` attribute has absolutely nothing to do with that; it only effects the stack order of the element, otherwise it is position-agnostic.

Which is why I referred you to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwCsg/); an alternative to help fix your woes.

Comment: what does that have to do with the question??? i dont want that error div to integrate into that fieldset...

Comment: @bonny I misunderstood the question; it was a bit different when I had originally started writing my answer. Regardless, updated my answer. Take care!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<li class="fr">
    <label for="a">a</label>
    <input class="err" type="text" id="a" name="a" value="" tabindex="20" autocomplete="off"/>
    <div class='erl'> Error text</div>
    <div class="sp"></div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
//for label
.fr label, .fr .err, .fr .erl {
    float:left;
}
.fr .sp {
    clear:both;
}
```